# how to view debugging in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging

When I debug in eclipse the debug window show lots of files. If I hit F6 again and again but dont actually know what is happening.

What am I doing wrong?  Can anyone help me find a good tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

This should help:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this tutorial will help you: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html - it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Some more additional information on debugging using eclipse:

http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2221711/Debugging-a-Java-Program-with-Eclipse.htm